# Laravel blade route to show method on title

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've got this route in a blade template:

```
<a href="{{route('docs', ['title' => $doc->slug])}}">{{$doc->title}}</a>
```

This gives the link an `href` like: 
`/docs?title=installation`

This works so that is nice. Laravel automatically translates this URL into `/docs/installation`.

**But I rather have the `href` containing the `/docs/installation` path.**

How to do that?

**Update:**
This is how the Route looks like in `web.php`.

```
Route::resource('docs', 'DocsController')->name('index', 'docs');
```

Comment: How does Laravel  translates your URL into `/docs/installation` ?

Comment: Not a clue. But the href /docs?title=installation redirects to /docs/installation.

Comment: `php artisan route:list`  and put this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is

```
<a href="{{route('docs.show', $doc->slug)}}">{{$doc->title}}</a> 
{{-- This route will generate an URL looks like 'docs/{whatever}'  --}}
```

Then in your web.php file

```
Route::resource('docs', 'DocsController')->name('docs');
```

And Finally in your DocsController

```
public function show($slug) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Nice, that was it! You instantly understand me. If you were a women we would have an amazing relationship.